# Traverse JSON Schema in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, schema

I'm trying to do some code-generation from JSON data. I'm getting some AWS backup data into a JSON file. I grab the first record and generate a json schema from that one line.

When I load the schema in Powershell, I can't enumerate the properties because they are deserialzed as primary properties, not as an array within "properties". This looks like a json schema thing where the list of properties is shown as an object list and not an array, but I'm not sure.

I'm guessing the Powershell JSON parser can't see an array there, so just makes them properties.

I really don't want to manually traverse the schema JSON to get the list of properties and their types.

schema.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description": "",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "definition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "calcDefFilters": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "l": {
          "type": "array",
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "required": [],
            "properties": {
              "m": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "field": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  },
                  "operator": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "field",
                  "value",
                  "operator"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "l"
      ]
    },
    "calculationId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "calcDefParameters": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "l": {
          "type": "array",
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "required": [],
            "properties": {
              "m": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "name": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "n": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "n"
                    ]
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "name",
                  "value",
                  "type"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "l"
      ]
    },
    "runId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "externalId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "dealVersionId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "definition",
    "calcDefFilters",
    "calculationId",
    "calcDefParameters",
    "runId",
    "type",
    "externalId",
    "dealVersionId"
  ]
}
```

This is what I get in Powershell:

```psh
[DBG]: PS C:\Scripts>> $prop


definition        : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
calcDefFilters    : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
calculationId     : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
calcDefParameters : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
runId             : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
type              : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
externalId        : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
dealVersionId     : @{type=object; properties=; required=System.Object[]}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Ehh, `properties` is *not* an array, json grammar for that would be `properties: [ ... ]` not `properties: { ... }`

Comment: Right. So JSON schema's don't do properties in an array. I'm out of luck then?

Comment: [Looping through each NoteProperty in a custom object](//stackoverflow.com/q/27642169)

Comment: What about nested NoteProperty values?

Comment: I hate to say it, but I just couldn't figure this out in PowerShell. I moved the logic to C# and I'm nearly done. It's still weird, but the JSON.net parser seems to do a better job if you tell it the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it answer but you can do it like this :

```
$a = @"
{
  "`$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description": "",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "definition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "calcDefFilters": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "l": {
          "type": "array",
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "required": [],
            "properties": {
              "m": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "field": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  },
                  "operator": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "field",
                  "value",
                  "operator"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "l"
      ]
    },
    "calculationId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "calcDefParameters": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "l": {
          "type": "array",
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "required": [],
            "properties": {
              "m": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "name": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "n": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "n"
                    ]
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "s": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "s"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "name",
                  "value",
                  "type"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "l"
      ]
    },
    "runId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "externalId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    },
    "dealVersionId": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "s": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "s"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "definition",
    "calcDefFilters",
    "calculationId",
    "calcDefParameters",
    "runId",
    "type",
    "externalId",
    "dealVersionId"
  ]
}
"@

$b = $a | ConvertFrom-Json 
$properties = $b.properties.Psobject.Members | where {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | % {$_.Name}
```

Comment: That gets me to the top level, but not the next level down properties.

Comment: You can do it recursively.